# Unable to fix the problem of addition of new todos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made this Todo project wherein one can add todos, delete them and line-through the ones that have been completed but *I am facing problem in adding a new todo to the list i.e it every time on the addition of a new todo leaves an alternative space blank, unable to find the bug*.

Following is the js file:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");

});


$("ul").on("click","span",function(event){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
event.stopPropagation();
});


$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){

    if(event.which === 13)
    {
        var todosText=$(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></span> " + todosText + "<li>")

    }

});

$(".fa-pencil-square").click(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle();
});
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assests/css/todos.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gayathri|Open+Sans:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gayathri:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    <h1 >TO-DO LIST <i class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
    <ul>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Check the theme</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Go to the store</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Select dress </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/todos.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paste your css as well.

Comment: Closing question as Typo (Missing `/` in `</li>`)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close the `li` tag in function that adds new todos:

```
$("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></span> " + todosText + "<li>")
```

should be

```
$("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></span> " + todosText + "</li>")
```